# What's the easiest way to get contact info from gmail into Mac's Address Book?

Tags: gmail, contacts

Do you know how mail.app makes it easy to add address info from an email sig into the Mac's Address Book?

Well, I don't use mail.app, but I'd like to find a similar way to do that with gmail.

Basically, when someone sends me an email with their name, address, phone number, etc, I want to easily add that info to my address book.

Answer (score 2):

This may be broader than what you are looking for, but in gmail you can go to `Contacts -> More -> Export` and make sure you select vCard Format.

 Then just open the file that downloads to your computer and it should add the contacts to your address book!
 [image: step 1: get to contacts] 
[image: Step 2: click more and then export] 
[image: Step 3: make sure you select the vCard option, then click Export!]

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm trying to do is pull out the info that people entered in their signature line. I'm not trying to export, but thank you for the hard work you put into the screenshots.

Comment: Oh I see I slightly misread the question! hahaha

Comment: It's still very useful.